# Trying to install jqt, it says link group is broken

Tags: j

The error message I get when jqt is run is libjqt.so.9.01: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

before this, it said the link group was broken.

Running Debian Bullseye amd64

Comment: I think your quickest solution is to head to the General Forum (subscribe if you are not already) and ask that same question, then come back here and fill in the answer when you find one that works for you (for someone who has the same question as you) http://www.jsoftware.com/mailman/listinfo/general

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved by:

1. Downloading jqt_j901_amd64.deb from jsoftware.com
2. Extracting the .deb
3. Manually copying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjqt.so into place
4. Creating a symlink from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjqt.so.9.01 to libjqt.so